# Angular 10: subscribing to an observable won't fire after a next call

Tags: angular, observable, angular10

I have a very simple scenario of subscribing to an Observable via an injected `FooService`:

`foo.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {    
    private foosSubject = new Subject<FooModelDTO[]>();        
    
    constructor() {
      this.setFoos([{id: "Some Id"}]);
    }
    setFoos(foos) {
        console.log("FooService.setFoos", foos);
        this.foosSubject.next(foos);
    }

    onFoos(): Observable<FooModelDTO[]> {
        return this.foosSubject.asObservable();
    }    
}
```

`app.componenet.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent  {
    private fooSubscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private _fooService: FooService) { 
      this.fooSubscription = this._fooService.onFoos()
      .subscribe({
        next: this.handleSubscription.bind(this)
      });      
    }

    handleSubscription(foosModels: FooModelDTO[]) {
        console.log("Yes!!!!"); <--- I'm not getting here!
    }
}
```

My question:

Why I'm am not able to fire the `handleSubscription` method via `subscribe`'s `next`?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-21oraq)

Comment: this can't have ever worked the way you have it. the next call on your subject is happening in the service constructor, which logically happens before the subscription in your component constructor. So it'd never be subscribed when next is called, as that's standard subject behavior. If you want the most recent value to go to new subscribers, you need to use `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: Thanks, you could have post is as an answer.